# Unital Commutative Banach $*$-algebra has $1^*=1$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-algebras

I am wondering why $1^*=1$ in a unital commutative Banach $*$-algebra.

I guess I am having trouble with comprehending what the $*$-algebra is.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a unit is unique, and consider the computation:
\begin{equation}
 a^{*} = (1a)^{*} = a^{*} 1^{*} = 1^{*} a^{*},
\end{equation}
where $a$ is any element in the Banach algebra. We see that $1^{*}$ is a unit, and by uniqueness of the unit it follows that $1^{*} = 1$.